# How to change solution name background in VS2019's main window

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2019

I'm using the **Color Theme Designer** extension for **Visual Studio 2019 v. 16.7.5** ([link to extension here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner)). With it, I've tweaked one of the themes to be a little pleasing for my eyes.

But, I'm stuck with one particular element on the main window - the Name (caption ?) of the current opened solution which is right next to a Search pane. It gets some white-ish background, but that I really don't want. See:

[image: annoying solution name element in title]

I woul'd like it to appear with the same background color as the rest of the window.

The original Dark Theme has it set to black, so It has to be possible:

[image]

I went intuivitelly through all possible properties of the theme - like *Title, *Caption etc. but I just can't find the right one. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: I have the same problem, so I opened a [feedback at vs developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/How-to-change-solution-name-background/1374546). 

I also noticed there has been opened an issue in the [theme editor repo](https://github.com/microsoft/VS-ColorThemes/issues/86)